Swift 6 concurrency issue with EnvironmentKey
I hav a fairly simple construct, that has worked fine up until I tried to switch Swift language version to 6.0:
private struct SomeHeightKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height }
}

public extension EnvironmentValues {
    var someHeight: CGFloat {
        get { self[SomeHeightKey.self] }
        set { self[SomeHeightKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}


Now there seems to be an issue about defaultValue: Main actor-isolated class property 'main' can not be referenced from a nonisolated context.
And apparently the EnvironmentKey protocol requires it to be nonisolated to uphold protocol conformance.
I have spent hours with ChatGPT and Copilot trying to find a concurrency safe way around this, but no luck so far. What am I missing here? I am both looking for the correct way of doing this in Swift 6 as well as any workaround that will allow me to postpone fixing it, but still migrate the rest of the codebase to Swift 6.
Ultimately the value is used for a ScrollViewWrapper:
public struct ScrollViewWrapper<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    public init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                content().frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height)
            }
            .frame(height: proxy.size.height)
            .environment(\.someHeight, proxy.size.height)
        }
    }
}

This is inherited code, that I am trying to migrate - not being an expert in SwiftUI, I am not even sure what they were trying to accomplish here. But perhaps the answer is to find a different way of doing this altogether...

Using UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height is a code smell. You should not be using that in SwiftUI in the first place. This is an XY Problem.

Thanks for your reply - I have updated my question with a little more context

So you are not using  the default value of the environment key? You are always setting the environment value explicitly using .environment(\.someHeight, ...) right? Well then you might as well just set it to 0, like static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0.

@SuneRiedel – I might suggest that you consider accepting Sweeper’s answer. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

If you are always setting the environment value with .environment(\.someHeight, proxy.size.height), the default value doesn't really matter, so you can just set it to some constant value:
static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0

In Xcode 16, you can also remove SomeHeightKey and use the Entry macro in the EnvironmentValues extension directly:
extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var someHeight: CGFloat = 0
}

If you do need to use a main actor isolated value as the default value of an environment key, you can set that as the environment value at the root of your view hierarchy.
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .environment(\.someKey, someMainActorIsolatedValue)
}

But I wouldn't do this with UIScreen.main.bounds.height. If you need to know how much space is available for a view, use a GeometryReader like you have shown. And most of the time you don't even need a geometry reader, since there are many other modifiers that help you layout views, like containerRelativeFrame.
